# C# Refactoring Code

Tags: c#, refactoring

Currently I have code that looks like this

```
Status("Start Step 1");
result = Step1();
Status("End Step 1", result);

Status("Start Step 2");
result = Step2();
Status("End Step 2", result);

Status("Start Step 3");
result = Step3();
Status("End Step 3", result);
```

Would it be possible to somehow refactor this code and get rid of the status lines. -- however it is very important to update the status at the start and end of each step.

I thought about moving the status lines into the Step1,2,3 calls but that just clutters up the methods.

Comment: Create a function that accepts a lambda (containing Step1, 2, 3...). Call that functon with appropriate lambda; have it increment a local step number, and print "Start <step>", do the lambda, print "End Step".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
public void ExecuteAndLog(Func<T> func, string startMessage, string endMessage) {
    Status(startMessage);
    var result = func;
    Status(endMessage, result);
}
```

with the obvious invocations

You can refine as needed. For example, building on the previous:

```
public void ExecuteAndLog(Func<T> func, string message) {
    ExecuteAndLog(func, "Start " + message, "End " + message);
}
```

making the invocations slightly simpler and even

```
public void ExecuteAndLog(Func<T> func, int stepNumber) {
    ExecuteAndLog(func, String.Format("Step {0}", stepNumber));
}
```

building on the previous. So now you can say

```
ExecuteAndLog(Step1, 1);
ExecuteAndLog(Step2, 2);
ExecuteAndLog(Step3, 3);
```

Comment: +1, but recommend placing `func` last. The call would then be `ExecuteAndLog("Start step 1", "End step 1", ()=>Step1())`

Answer (score 1):

Slight improvement over @Jason

```
public object ExecuteAndLog(Func<T> func, int number) {
    Status(string.Format("Start Step {0}", number));
    var result = func;
    Status(string.Format("End Step {0}", number), result);
    return result;
}

// and used like:

var result = ExecuteAndLog(Step1, 1);
result = ExecuteAndLog(Step2, 2);
result = ExecuteAndLog(Step3, 3);
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this:

```
public void RunStep<T>(string stepName, Func<T> stepFunc)
    {
        Status("Start Step " + stepName);
        var result = stepFunc();
        Status("End Step " + stepName, result);
    }
```

Which would be called like:

```
RunStep("1", Step1);
RunStep("2", Step2);
RunStep("3", Step3);
```

Answer (score 0):

if they all return the same result type you can do that like

```
    Runner(Step1, Step2, Step3);


    public void Runner<T>(params Func<T>[] stepList)
    {
        foreach (var act in stepList)
        {
            Status(act.Method.Name + "Started");
            var result=act.Invoke();
            Status(act.Method.Name + "Ended", result);  
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Spring.Net logger to avoid calling Status again and again.

Thanks.